# Calculate sum of two datetime fields

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a way to add 2 hours field

```
Field 1:1:09:03
Field 2:0:15:20
Total:  1:24:23
```

Comment: We can't really help you without more details: Oracle? MySQL? can you convert them in number and do the operation if you want.

Comment: What is the data type of those columns? And which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using MsSQL. they are varchar.

Comment: Why are you storing times as varchar?

Answer (score 2):

in MySQL you can use

```
select addtime(field1, field2) as total
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine these 2 functions: 
--extract hour from datetime

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())
```

-- add hours (in that case 2) to the datetime

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 2, GETDATE())
```